# Webpack: How to add a content hash of js file for JSON

Tags: json, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome-extension with webpack and am building my javascript file names using contenthash

`webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js",
    popup: "./src/popup.js",
    background: "./src/background.js",
  },

  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
}
```

In the same directory, I have my `manifest.json` where I need to reference my `background.[contenthash].js` file. (To simplify, I have left out some fields)

`manifest.json`

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "*",
  "version": "*",
  "description": "*",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "author": "*",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.*.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
}
```

I tried to access my `background.[contenthash].js` file by using `scripts: [ background.*.js ]` but I am unable to do so. I was thinking of just not using the contenthash all together for simplification, but I would prefer to have it. To clarify, they are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`webpack-manifest-plugin`](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin) in order to generate a manifest with file mapping, after the build, you can read it, and change the `background` field at the end.

A cool setup may be achieved by writing a custom webpack plugin which will load the `manifest.json` from **src** folder, change the required fields (`version`, `background` etc) and add it to be emitted to the `dist` folder.